# Typoscript menu doesn't show 2nd level

Tags: typo3, typoscript

My problem is, that for some reason my 2nd level menu doesn't show up at all. I checked everything I'm familiar with, but i can't figure it out.

So, here is my typoscript:

```
lib.navigation_level1 = COA
lib.navigation_level1 {
10 = HMENU
10 {
expAll = 1

special.value = 1

# first level
1 = TMENU
1 {
    wrap = <nav class="w-nav-menu menuebar" role="navigation">|</nav>

    NO = 1
    NO {
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ATagParams = class="w-nav-link menue" style="max-width: 940px"
    }

    IFSUB = < .NO
    IFSUB {
        allWrap = <div class="w-dropdown" style="max-width:940px"><div class="w-dropdown-toggle menue">|</div></div>
        stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
        ATagParams = style="max-width: 940px;"
        doNotLinkIt = 1
    }

 }  


    2 < .1
    2.wrap = <nav class="w-dropdown-list dropdownliste">|</nav>
    }
}
```

The items, which have further sites, are surrounded by the correct class. So this `IFSUB` seems to be correct.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like i havn't tried everything.
I had to put the "expAll" on the TMENU and not on the HMENU

Comment: @lorenz i can accept it in two days. Can't accept it right now, otherwise i would have done that already :)